# Remove documents from a MongoDB collection based on "time" of a Date field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection which stores documents with the following structure:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(-6225637853094968071), 
    "Id" : "1585534", 
    "Type" : NumberInt(42), 
    "InDate" : ISODate("2017-10-05T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(-622563784353458071), 
    "Id" : "15832422", 
    "Type" : NumberInt(42), 
    "InDate" : ISODate("2017-10-06T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
}
```

I want to delete all documents with a particular "Id" and "Type" where the "InDate" field has time `18:30:00.000+0000`. I tried using this query:

```
 db.collection.remove({
"ChannelType": NumberInt(28),
"HotelId": "1585534",
"CheckInDate": /$18:30:00.000+0000/
})
```

but it doesnt work. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Regular Expression will not work on something that is not a string. There actually is no simple way of selecting a `BSON Date` by purely it's time value in a regular query expression.

In order to do this you would supply a [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) condition with the additional logic to match on just the **time** portion of the date value.

Based on the data actually supplied in the question:

```
db.getCollection('collection').remove({
  "Id": "1585534",
  "Type": NumberInt(42),
  "$where": function() {
    return this.InDate.getUTCHours() === 18
      && this.InDate.getUTCMinutes() === 30
  }
})
```

Which is of course just the first document in the provided data, even though it's really just identified by `"Id"` anyway since that value is unique between the two.

The [`.getUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMinutes) and [`.getUTCMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMinutes) are JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object methods, which is how a `BSON Date` is expressed when used within a [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) expression.

---

Trivially, MongoDB 3.6 ( upcoming as of writing ) allows a more efficient form than [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) in aggregation expressions:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "Id": "1585534",
    "Type": NumberInt(42),
    "$expr": {
      "$and": [
        { "$eq": [{ "$hour": "$InDate" }, 18 ] },
        { "$eq": [{ "$minute": "$InDate" }, 30] } 
      ] 
    }   
  }}
])
```

However such expressions cannot be used directly with methods such as [`.remove()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) or [`.deleteMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/), but [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) expressions can.

Comment: I want to delete all docs with a certain date from Nodejs. So I learned not to query the iso date directly -as it is a string and not a date - but use the function `ISODate(my-iso)` which is in Node `new Date(123T45Z).toISOString()`. I call my own defined func like `remove_many('sysinfo', new Date('2022-05-18T13:55:37.210Z').toISOString(), 'date')`, but it does not work. It is `remove_many(collection,value,field)`. Any help?

Comment: I got it, not putting the toIsoString() and it works because Mongo stores an object, and with the method you get a string.So querying for the `new Date('string')`..

Answer (score 1):

Iso date don't match a string, you need to use isodate in the query too

```
db.collection.remove({
    "ChannelType": NumberInt(28),
    "HotelId": "1585534",
    "InDate": ISODate(2017-10-05T18:30:00.000+0000)
})
```

Comment: Which also will not work, since it's not a valid value. Perhaps you should have actually tried that in a shell before you answered.

Comment: tried it, just wrong copy/past. Updated it. Thanks for showing the mistake

Comment: I believe the spirit of the question is is "more than one possible date" and therefore "just using the **time** value" and not the whole date. Hence why you tried your incorrect syntax in the first place, and hence why you would still be incorrect even if the still incorrect syntax was corrected.

Comment: In Node `ISODate()` will be `new Date(123).toISOString()`